# LCD data read and show on computer

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, lcd

[image: LCD screen shot]I have a project to work as follow: 
this is a PIC based (PIC16C62B) porudct which measures value coming from mechanical gyro sensor. analog data from gyro amplified and sent to AD7707 to convert into serial. PIC reads this serial of AD7707 and shows gyro values/data on 16x2 LCD after internal processing. I dont know about the internal program/code of PIC being used into it. the PIC is code protected and I cannot read its hex. now I am required to show LCD vlues/data same on computer in any case.

I dont understand how to do it. if anyone have any idea to do this or had worked on please help me in this situation. I will  be thankful for all positive response.

```
char a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,var;
char i=0;
char con=0;
char low=0;

//byte sBuffer[256];
//unsigned int nLen;

//nLen = HexToASCII(sBuffer, "65 66 67");

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(1200);
 //pinMode(13, INPUT);
pinMode(12,INPUT);    //Define RS
pinMode(11,INPUT);    //Define EN
pinMode(5,INPUT);
pinMode(4,INPUT); 
pinMode(3,INPUT);
pinMode(2,INPUT);
pinMode(9,INPUT);
pinMode(8,INPUT);
pinMode(7,INPUT);
pinMode(6,INPUT);
  a=0;
   b=0;
   c=0;
   d=0;
   e=0;
   f=0;
   g=0;
   h=0;
   con=0;
   low=0;
}

void loop() {




  if(digitalRead(11)==HIGH && low==0)                //EN hight
  {
    low=1;
  }
  if(digitalRead(11)==LOW && low==1){
     if (digitalRead(12)==HIGH){                     //RS high
   a=digitalRead(9);
   b=digitalRead(8);
   c=digitalRead(7);
   d=digitalRead(6);
   e=digitalRead(5);
   f=digitalRead(4);
   g=digitalRead(3);
   h=digitalRead(2);
//   var = (h*128)+(g*64)+(f*32)+(e*16)+(d*8)+(c*4)+(b*2)+(a*1);
   var = (h<<7)+(g<<6)+(f<<5)+(e<<4)+(d<<3)+(c<<2)+(b<<1)+(a);

   con=1;
   low=0;
   }
  }
  if(con==1){
  //  String str(var);
    Serial.print(var);
    //Serial.print("\n");
     a=0;
     b=0;
     c=0;
     d=0;
     e=0;
     f=0;
     g=0;
     h=0;
     con=0;
     var=0;
  }

}
```

[image: connection of LCD with Arduino]

Comment: You will have to provide a great more detail than that; obligatory "we are not psychic".

Comment: sure dude. I understand. I edit my question and give more details that I am able to give. thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've got

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgwKOq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and you want to tap off the data somewhere. You have two choices:

- Tap off the digital signal before the PIC and write your own code to process the data and display it.
- Monitor the parallel data into the LCD. To do this you would need to monitor all the data lines with a micro - Arduino, for example. In micro memory create 2 * 16 memory registers and figure out what each command written to the LCD means and update your registers with the displayed values. You then transmit all 32 registers or the few you're interested in to your PC over serial.

[image: Arduino LCD]

*Arduino.cc image of LCD setup. In your case you would be monitoring the LCD rather than writing to it.*

I hope you have plenty of time available. Your going to need it.

### Pseudo code

The main problem here will be keeping up with the LCD writing while trying to serial print the received data. I suggest that you try and capture one complete LCD update, serial print it, then wait for the start of the next update. (Watch for control code to move back to position 0 or whatever.)

```
void setup() {
  int chars[80]; // Line 1 uses DDRAM address 0x00 to 0x0F.
                 // Line 2 uses DDRAM address 0x40 to 0x4F.
}

void loop() {
  if(picWriting) {
    char = readLCDdata();            // Read the LCD byte.
    if(isControlCode) {              // Is it a control code or a character?
      updateLcdDdramPointer(char);   // Point to the array location for this character.
    } else {
      storeCharacter(char, pointer); // Put this character into the array.
    }
  }
  if(pointer == lastChar) {          // The last character has been read.
    // Serial.print out all the characters of interest.
  }
  // If printing takes too long the PIC may have started updating the display already.
  // Wait for start of next LCD refresh.
}
```

Comment: If I create new code to read serial of AD7707 then much difficult because of sensor calibration used. so I prefer to fetch data parallel from LCD pins. to implement this, I am not able to open schematic and Arduino code images attached in answer. please attach images again. also note that PIC sends 8bit data to LCD. thanx transistor

Comment: There is no schematic and no Arduino code image in my answer. Just a block diagram (that you should have created for your question) and a typical Arduino LCD setup. Your job will be easier with 8-bit data to LCD.

Comment: I did it by reading all parallel data bits of 16x2 LCD on arduino leonardo. it starts get data and sends serial to computer successfully but the problem is that some of data is missing... like if data on lcd is 6 digit 123456 then continuously received data is like 125623 etc as random... i think some computation is involved and pointer is busy in doing serial and misses some data. now how can I solve it....?

Comment: That was quick! Edit your post and include a schematic of how you are connecting to the LCD. How do you know when to read?

Comment: according to LCD data read and writing timing diagram, when en pin is high then read data.

Comment: You probably want to wait for the rising edge of the enable pin before reading the parallel pins, since thats when data is clocked into the lcd. You may also need to recognize when some commands (like Goto) are sent to the lcd; of course this depends on how much of the lcd's functions are being used. If all that is displayed is a number on the first row, constantly being overwritten, then you only need to know when the Goto command is sent, so that you can know when a new sensor value is being sent. So you watch the E line (to know when to read) and also the RS line (to identify commands)

Comment: If you are still seeing 'received data is like 125623 etc as random' then maybe your code is missing characters from the PIC while the Arduino is busy. Q1: Are you sending the data out of the Arduino serially? Q2: Can you give us a look at the relevant parts of your code - or a high-level flowchart?

Comment: I am also monitoring RS pin where valid data is being received. yes, I am sending data out serialy so that I can see it on serial monitor in Aarduino environment.   I attach image of code have used.

Comment: @abdulrazzaq: You posted the code in my answer instead of in your post. I rejected the edit. Please post code as _code_ and not a screen-grab. I can't edit a screen-grab. Edit your post, copy your Arduino code in. Select it. Click the " button to convert it to code. Save Edits.

Comment: According to your schematic the LCD is LM016L. Here is a [good tutorial](https://embeddedcenter.wordpress.com/ece-study-centre/display-module/lcd-16x2-lm016l/). You're going to have to figure out which digit is which. Can you add the LCD layout to your question?

Comment: i m not getting, how to attach code..

Comment: i have pasted an image of lcd connections layout.

Comment: You don't 'attach' code, you paste it into your question and then format it as code using the " button. Sorry, by LCD layout I mean show us all the information on the LCD screen so we know what row and column the characters are in. A photo would do.

Comment: hi, I changed my own code and read data only when RS pin is high and  I succeeded to get all data accurately. now my problem has solved 100%. thank you for you help. :)

Comment: Congratulations! Can you post the code? It could help someone in future. Put it in your original question with a 'solution' heading.